# Get filepath after upload using uploadify without onComplete event?

Tags: php, uploadify

I've been searching here and Google to find a working solution to get the filepath after upload using uploadify without onComplete event??

I'm using the latest version of Uploadify Version 3.2 which doesn't include onComplete event. 
check the event list:
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

So I can't use that event.

I use the following code for the index.php as it comes with download files:

```
<body>
<h1>Uploadify Demo</h1>
<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I modified the uploadify.php to set new names for the uploaded files to avoid any problem while uploading the files as the following:

```
$new_name=microtime();
$new_name=str_replace(".","",$new_name);
$new_name=str_replace(" ","",$new_name);
$store_dir="uploaded/"; //directory to place uploaded files
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];    
$fileTmp = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
$fileSize = ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024 / 1000);
$extension = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, "."));
$extension = strtolower($extension);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $store_dir.$new_name.$extension);
```

So how to get the path to the uploaded file or even just the new file name.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: File path is not being shown as the security reasons are concerned. you can get the file name using `'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) { alert(file.name); }`

Answer (score 0):

you should return some json from script.

echo json_encode(array('file' => $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $store_dir.$new_name.$extension));

and then handle it by javascript